# Django Virtual Environment Setup

Tags: django, backend

I just started working on a Django project. In the beginning, the vscode terminal was working fine and executing the virtual environment created by pipenv for the project, but when I opened the project again, I got this error and was unable to open the virtual environment interpreter.

Error message in Terminal:

PS E:\Work space\Django> & C:/Users/hp/.virtualenvs/Django-aOoBcd7m/Scripts/Activate.ps1

& : File C:\Users\hp.virtualenvs\Django-aOoBcd7m\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

At line:1 char:3

- & C:/Users/hp/.virtualenvs/Django-aOoBcd7m/Scripts/Activate.ps1
- 
- CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

how can i fix this ?

I tried to change the ExecutionPolicy to RemoteSigned in powershell after that its working, but is there any other way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi instead of changing the ExecutionPolicy to RemoteSigned. You can bypass the policy only for that script execution. Try any of the below commands it should work.(Run PowerShell as administrator)

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:/Users/hp/.virtualenvs/Django-aOoBcd7m/Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command { & 'C:\Users\hp\.virtualenvs\Django-aOoBcd7m\Scripts\Activate.ps1' }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. After executing the command, the virtual environment is working.